# @Transactional and serializable level problem

Tags: jpa, isolation-level

I have a problem with isolation levels in JPA. For example I have following code:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void first() {
    Obj obj = new Obj();
    obj.setName("t");
    objDAO.save(obj);
    second();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void second(){
    List<Obj> objs = objDAO.findAll();
}
```

In my opinion the second method should not see uncomitted changes from method first. So new object with name "t" should not be visible till commit (but it is).
If I am wrong, then please, give me example in JPA where it won't be visible. Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If your methods are inside one class it will not work because container will treat this as a single transaction. The container doesn't know that you want to create new transaction.

From the Spring reference:

> Note: In proxy mode (which is the default), only 'external' method calls coming in through the proxy will be intercepted. This means that 'self-invocation', i.e. a method within the target object calling some other method of the target object, won't lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional!

If you want to call method second() in new transaction you can try this:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void first() {
    Obj obj = new Obj();
    obj.setName("t");
    objDAO.save(obj);
    applicationContext.getBean(getClass()).second();
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void second(){
    List<Obj> objs = objDAO.findAll();
}
```

Comment: So have You any example of this behaviour?

Comment: I added an example to my answer, take a look and tell if it works

Comment: Yes, second() method does not see changes. Many thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, so one more question, if I change isolation level to read uncommitted then it seond should see changes with given propagation... but it does not...

Comment: And if first is SERIALIZABLE then second when creates new transaction should not have access to table and throw error...